# Get single elements from nested list based on index position indecated of the value in a second list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As last part of a bigger project here is what I am trying to solve:

I have a list of lists of which I need to extract exactlty one element based on the value of a second list.

```
a = [[6,2,3,9], [10,19,14,11], [27,28,21,24]]

b = [0,2,2]
```

The values in `b` indicate the positions of the elements in the sublists. Also, the index in `b` is the true for the index of elements in list `a`.

The result I am looking for is:

```
c = [6, 14, 21]
```

I have tried many versions of this:

```
c = [i[j] for i in a for j in b]
```

But as a result I get a list over all emements of all lists looking like this:

```
c = [6, 3, 3, 10, 14, 14, 27, 21, 21]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using nested loops, you are combining *every* element from `a` with *every* element from `b`. What you want is *pair-wise* iteration, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
c = [x[y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [6, 14, 21]
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
c = [a[i][b[i]] for i in range(min(len(a), len(b)))]
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I did not use zip before in this way. But this seems to be really a fast and simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
[v[b[i]] for i,v in enumerate(a)]
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [[6,2,3,9], [10,19,14,11], [27,28,21,24]]
>>> b = [0,2,2]
>>> [v[b[i]] for i,v in enumerate(a)]
[6, 14, 21]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
c = [a[i][b[i]] for i in xrange(len(b))]
```

Comment: Or we can use enumerate(b)

Comment: this is just so un-pythonic

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following.

```
a = [[6,2,3,9], [10,19,14,11], [27,28,21,24]]
b = [0,2,2]
c = []
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    c.append(a[i][b[i]])
print (c)
```

Comment: this is just horribly un-pythonic

Comment: yes but this is just an option and as easier for a newbie to start on :)